# disable library in gradle for specific activity

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am developing an application which has an activity where record audio and make FFT simultaniously. also displaying animation like sonar on the screen. in order to make FFT simultaniously, app should be processing fast. 
In my tests, the app was doing ffts in 20 ms which is very good before android fill the next buffer. But after I have add some libraries in dependencies/ build.gradle, eventhough that recording activity has nothing to do with that library, its fft duration increase dramatically to 400ms and it cant finish the fft process before the next buffer. and it cause problems 
My question is; can I disable some libraries for some activities?

the problematic library is  'com.goseamless:seamless:2.4.0'  which is ad network library.
In order to make it run, I need to enable multidex. 
After adding it and enabling multidex, the problem above occurs

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION
//compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1254'

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION
    targetSdkVersion ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
        //incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

repositories {
maven {
    url "http://maven.seamlessapi.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"
}
}

dependencies {
compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
compile project(':Libraries:CropImageLib')
compile project(':Libraries:facebook-android')
compile project(':Libraries:NineOldLibs')
compile project(':Libraries:SlidingMenu')
compile files('libs/JTransforms-3.0.jar')
compile files('libs/JLargeArrays-1.2.jar')
compile files('libs/gdata-core-1.0.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
compile 'com.goseamless:seamless:2.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

any idea???

Answer (score 0):

> My question is; can I disable some libraries for some activities?

Not from a Gradle standpoint.

> eventhough that recording activity has nothing to do with that library, its fft duration increase dramatically to 400ms and it cant finish the fft process before the next buffer. and it cause problems

Use tools like Traceview and systrace to determine exactly where the time is being spent. Then, figure out what you need to do to improve that. For example, perhaps there is some method on the ad views that you need to call from `onPause()` of your activity to get them to consume less CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem and the solution. The problem was 65k dex problem due to the ad network api which includes arount 40k methods. So I started shrink the libraries I use by getting the classes and adding them into the app as java file. So I could remove the libraries. Then when it went back to 65k , it start to work again. Let me know if you need more info. Also, I have used this great tool to understand which library has how many methods in detail. https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts